# How to use `calc` library `$...$` notation as an argument to anchor keys?

Tags: tikz-pgf

NOTE: I have edited the original question because it had incorrect information (my apologies).

I need to move green "little tag" node from its current position, as seen in the output below, some distance right.

I tried using calc's $...$ notation inside "above=0mm of ROW_1.north west" to subtract from (or add to) the "ROW_1.north west" coordinates but it didn't work.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node[fill=red](ROW_1){this is some line of text};
\path node
[   fill=green,
    above=0mm of ROW_1.north west,
    anchor=south west,
    scale=0.5
]{little tag};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What you've done should work, can you show us a complete example?

Comment: Is the node ROW_1 defined at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xshift`, or `above left=y and x of` instead.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node[fill=red](ROW_1){this is some line of text};
\path node
[   fill=green,
    above=0mm of ROW_1.north west,
    xshift=-5mm,
    anchor=south west,
    scale=0.5
] (lt) {little tag};

\path node
[   fill=green,
    above left=0mm and 5mm of lt.north west,
    anchor=south west,
    scale=0.5
]{little tag};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do calculations but imho (it looked like this before you edited the question) you had a parenthese to much, and missing braces:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node[fill=red](ROW_1){this is some line of text};
\path node
[   fill=green,
    above=0mm of {$(ROW_1.north west)-(2mm,0)$},
    anchor=south west,
    scale=0.5
]{little tag};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]